# Android AccountManager adds account, but dissapears after

Tags: android, authentication, android-4.4-kitkat, accountmanager

Recenlty i looked into making a single account for multiple apps. So i used the android AccountManager for it.
I set all the correct permissions in the manifest, added an authenticator.xml, created the service and all other things (also declared that in the manifest).

I created a small library/wrapper for myself to make the authentication process easier and let it work exactly the same across apps.

But now im in a situation that my code works in one app, but not in the other. The code im using is exactly the same.
I use the addAccountExplicitly method to add the account:

```
accountManager.addAccountExplicitly(account, password, bundle)
```

When i debug a line after, and go to the android account settings screen, my account appears. So i would think its not a problem with adding the account.
But then when i send a broadcast (or any other piece of code), and exit the loginActivity i created the account dissapears. So when calling:

```
AccountManager.get(context).getAccountsByType(ACCOUNT_TYPE)
```

returns null. Like you would expect since its not visible in the settings screen.

But then the weird part, in the other app, i use EXACTLY the same code, but the account isn't removed/deleted. 
When i call the getAccountsByType again it returns the account i just added.

Did i miss something in that app? I tried to compare everything to the other, but didn't find any differences.
Could anyone point me in the right direction here?

If anything is unclear, or you need more information, please let me know!

Help is much appreciated!

Note: This only happens on android 4.4.2 (or at least i noticed it didn't work in that version, any other version above 6.0.1 is working correctly).

EDIT: I refreshed the library (.aar) package, so both apps are identical. Now both apps won't work. When i click the login button, and save the account it appears in the settings, but when i go one step further in debugging mode (or just let it continue) it removes the account again!
I noticed that when i keep stepping over, it will eventually (after 10 times in that method) be removed in the build.looper function? (but my guess is that every class/object/piece of code will run that function)

EDIT2: Looked a bit around on what i was doing exactly. Since i was setting some paramters/variables to the account. I thought about removing the account first, and then re-add it (if there was an active account already).
But then i changed it to actually update those values instead of removing the whole account (which is better anyway), it worked!
So it seems android does not execute those lines in the correct way? Like things you would get in Hibernate sometimes? 
Thats my only explanation for now.